# SQL state [72000]; error code [14300]; Could not execute JDBC batch update

Tags: oracle, hibernate

JDBC exception on Hibernate data access: SQLException for SQL [insert into ..... statement]; SQL state [72000]; error code [14300]; Could not execute JDBC batch update; nested exception is org.hibernate.QueryTimeoutException: Could not execute JDBC batch update

I am getting this exception while inserting data into the table. Could someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I am able to find out. It occurred because while inserting the record into the table we are missing the partition key I.e partition key is null.

Answer (score 0):

There might be following case  :
Check table  capacity.
Invalid mapping 
check  your  hibernate configuration file